# Flask Yield don't work on Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, flask, yield, gevent

The following view only generate output during the execution on Firefox.
On Chrome the request flush the entire response once, when the `while` ends, at the end.

What are making the it don't work on Chrome?

```
@processes.route('/read_buffer/<int:pid>')
def read_buffer(pid):

    def generate():
        sent = 0
        while not settings.buffers[pid]['finished']:
            for i, row in enumerate(settings.buffers[pid]['lines'][sent:]):
                sent += 1
                yield row

            gevent.sleep(0.5)

    return flask.Response(
        response=generate(),
        status=200,
        mimetype="text/plain"
    )
```

App config:

```
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = False
app.register_blueprint(processes.processes, url_prefix='/processes')
CORS(app)
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode='gevent')
socketio.run(
    app=app,
    host=_config.get('server', 'host', fallback='0.0.0.0'),
    port=_config.getint('server', 'port', fallback=5000),
    use_reloader=False
)
```

I'm using the SocketIO because I'm using it in other places.

Answer (score 0):

seems like a known bug in Chrome:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=156023